# ng-repeat with nested json objects

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to create a nested ng-repeat that populates contacts names into buttons from the JSON objects. I cant seem to find the correct way to populate the info though. Can someone explain whats wrong with my ng-repeat?

http://plnkr.co/edit/B3g075?p=preview

```
    <!-- Contacts List Section -->
<div class="col-md-3 contact-list">
  <div class="list-group">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" ng-repeat="contact in groups.contacts" class="list-group-item" ng-click="selectContact(contact)">{{group.firstName}} {{group.lastName}}
      <span ng-click="deleteContact()" class="onHover pull-right"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></span>
    </a>
  </div>
  <button ng-click="isCreatingNewContact = true" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> New Contact</button>
</div>
```

`$scope.groups` has the following structure (shortened for brevity):

```
  $scope.groups = [
  {
    name: "Personal",
    contacts: [
      {
      "firstName": "Personal First Name",
      "lastName": "last name",
      // ...
      },
      { /* another contact */ },
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "Family",
    contacts: [ 
    // ...     
    ]
  },

];
```

Thanks

Comment: `group.contacts` DNE

Comment: Please post all the relevant code, like `groups.contacts` structure, in the question - just having a link to a plunker is not enough.

Comment: I've also tried `group.contacts` and it didnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice how here:

```
<div class="col-md-3 group-list">
  <!-- Groups Section -->
  <h4>Contact Groups</h4>
  <div class="list-group">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" ng-model="all" class="list-group-item">All Contacts</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" ng-repeat="group in groups" class="list-group-item">{{group.name}}
      <span ng-click="deleteGroup()" class="onHover pull-right"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></span>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-bottom">
    <button class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> New Group</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

You have an `ng-repeat="group in groups"` directive, iterating through the groups. The group you get while looping through groups is only active in the sub-scope of the `<a>` tag that you're calling the directive in.

You seem to want to get all of the `contact` objects of each object in `groups`. You'd have to iterate through the `groups` list again, and within that iteration, iterate through the objects in the group contacts. So something like:

```
<!-- Contacts List Section -->
<div class="col-md-3 contact-list">
  <div class="list-group">
    <div ng-repeat="group in groups">
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" ng-repeat="contact in group.contacts" class="list-group-item" ng-click="selectContact(contact)">{{contact.firstName}} {{contact.lastName}}
        <span ng-click="deleteContact()" class="onHover pull-right"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button ng-click="isCreatingNewContact = true" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> New Contact</button>
</div>
```

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/lqNd5yDC2QlrX0M9TjrP

Comment: No problem. If it fixes your issue, please remember to accept the answer. As an addition, I've added a plunker link at the bottom of the answer.